# WebKit and overflow: hidden affecting width

Tags: css, webkit, width, overflow, column-width

I'm having a problem with overflow and width in Google Chrome/Webkit. This is a follow-up question on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370342/css-float-bug-with-side-pane-resizing-main-content/), there you will find the CSS. I need to have `visibility: hidden` to fix the problem in the first question.

The problem is visible in the screenshots below.

Why does this attribute affect the width in Webkit? Can I solve this without nasty hacks? Or can I re-think my strategy for the right pane?

Main div with `overflow: visible`. The div is stretched to the right pane, as it should be.

[image: no overflow]

Main div with `overflow: hidden`. The right pane is now affecting the main div's width.

[image: overflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to "formatting context" : http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=6BC9D

"Floats don't overlap each other, and neither will a float overlap an element that establishes a new block formatting context."

If you use overflow: hidden to create a new block formatting context in the main div, you don't need the horizontal margins any more.